# Removing alkaline stain with acid

Tags: acid-base

Professor Robert Winston once removed a blue alkaline stain using carbon dioxide from a fire extinguisher on James Corden's show. Here's the link for the [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xn3ZwyIV3bs&)

I would like to know if there is a way to recreate this experiment at home. I guess instead of carbonic acid I could use lemon juice or a vinegar. I'm really not sure about the base though. Would baking soda mixed with blue food coloring do the trick? I have very small chemistry background so any help is appreciated. I'd like to recreate this experiment for entertainment purposses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that there are not many *alkaline stains* you will find on household objects. Professor Robert Winston just did a demo for attracting attention of the public towards science (so-called outreach experiments). He simply used an acid-base indicator, perhaps thymolphthalein, which is blue in basic medium and colorless in slightly acidic or even in slightly alkaline solutions. It was a nice demo.

[image]

However for entertainment purposes, you can try red cabbage stains or beet root and see the effect of adding vinegar or lemon on a piece of white cloth.